# Do mathematical realists believe that the continuum hypothesis is true?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy, incompleteness

The continuum hypothesis is known to be independent (neither provable nor disprovable) within the ZFC axioms. But as I understand it, [mathematical realists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics#Mathematical_realism) (e.g. Platonists) believe that there is a single "correct" model of mathematics that corresponds to the real world, and therefore that every well-formed mathematical proposition is either "actually true" or "actually false", regardless of whether it can be proven in any particular axiom system.

The continuum hypothesis is perhaps the simplest and most intuitive claim known to be undecidable within ZFC. Do most mathematical realists believe it to be true or false?

Comment: One sense of "mathematical realist" might be be living $V=L$, although Gödel himself seems to have thought it "obviouly untrue".  In any case the continuum hypothesis holds then.

Comment: To choose a model is OK, but to think that this model "corresponds to the real world" whatever this means, would be a huge overestimation of what mathematics can do.I heard that many mathematicians favour the possibility that the continuum hypothesis is false. Unfortunately , I do not remember details about the reasons.

Comment: I don't believe the truth (or not) of continuum hypothesis is a central issue for many "real world" mathematical applications.

Comment: @hardmath "V=L" ? Never heard of this...

Comment: @Peter: Here it means that the universal class and the class of *constructible sets* are equal, which is how Gödel showed (inter alia) the continuum hypothesis is consistent with ZFC.

Comment: @hardmath I heard of constructible sets. These sets all satisfy the continuum hypothesis, right ?

Comment: @Peter  Right.  Autocorrect was tormenting me in my last Comment posting.

Comment: My understanding is that amongst those mathematicians who believe CH has a definite truth value, the majority view is that it is probably false.

Comment: "corresponds to the real world" is to vague to be called true or false.

Comment: @BruceET. Not yet, anyway. Much of number theory had little application until (independently) researchers of MI-5 (U.K.) and NSA (U.S.A.) used it to invent a new kind of cryptography, using computers to do the massive amounts of arithmetic that it needed....

Comment: @Peter.  Kurt Godel (1930's) showed that if the axiom system $ZF$ is consistent then $V\ne L$ is $not$ a theorem of $ZF,$ so $Con (ZF)\to Con (ZF+(V=L)).$ The continuum hypothesis ($CH$) is a theorem of $ZF+(V=L).$ The axiom of choice ($AC$) is also a theorem of $ZF+(V=L).$ So $Con (ZF)\to Con (ZFC+CH).$... Paul Cohen (1960's) invented Forcing to show that $Con (ZFC)\to   Con (ZFC+(\neg CH).)$

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your question may be geography-dependent.  While on the West side of the Atlantic the dominant view is that CH is "probably false", on its East side and specifically in France, the opinions are heavily influenced by those of the Realist and Platonist [Alain Connes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Connes) who is convinced CH is *true*, as mentioned in [this publication](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-013-9340-0) and also [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.07.631).  Connes discusses CH in detail in his *A triangle of thought*.

You should realize that it is not just because one calls himself a realist that one necessarily believes that CH has a definite truth value in set theory.  Joel David Hamkins calls himself a realist; however he is not a realist of a set-theoretic *universe* but rather of a set-theoretic *multiverse*, where one slips effortlessly from a set-theoretic universe where CH is true to a set-theoretic universe where CH is false, at the click of a *switch*.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in the article I don't see any citation for Connes' belief that CH is true, and googling "Connes "continuum hypothesis"" doesn't pull anything up that I can tell; can you provide such?

Comment: The main source for this is his Triangle of Thought.  We mentioned this in at least two articles. @NoahSchweber

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not convinced. Your linked articles mention that Connes *uses* CH, but that doesn't mean he *believes it is true* in a Platonic sense. I can't immediately find anything (including in your linked articles) where he asserts this stronger claim. Even a Platonist may prove theorems in a system whose truth they are not convinced of. "[Connes] is convinced CH is true" is quite a strong claim, and I don't yet see any strong evidence for it. (cont'd)

Comment: As to "A triangle of thoughts," I don't have it on hand, but amazon's book search pulls up only one instance of the phrase "continuum hypothesis," and just as an example of a ZFC-undecidable sentence. Can you provide a *quote* from Connes, demonstrating that he "is convinced CH is true" (rather than an extrapolation of his philosophical position from the axiom system he uses)? Or that belief in CH is widespread on the east of the Atlantic?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, it's been a while since we worked on this so it may take me time to provide the details you request, but Connes definitely is a believer in CH and decidedly not AC, even though such a position may not be completely coherent from the point of view of logic (*in a sense* CH is a stronger form of AC). If France had a strong contingent of logicians or set theorists they would probably not automatically subscribe to Connes' views but as Adriano Mathias richly documented logic in France has been systematically persecuted because of the Bourbaki prejudices on foundations.

Comment: "f France had a strong contingent of logicians or set theorists they would probably not automatically subscribe to Connes' views" OK, but *still*: can you provide evidence for the claim that "specifically in France, the opinions are heavily influenced by those of the Realist and Platonist Alain Connes who is convinced CH is true"? I'm not being willfully obtuse here, I honestly don't see any evidence of this or of the broader claim that belief in CH is widespread east of the Atlantic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, whoever is familiar with the mathematical landscape in France knows how hugely influential Alain Connes is there. I don't have solid evidence for belief in CH other than Connes' views and the fact of his influence.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't disputing Connes' influence in France, but rather (granting his belief in CH for the moment) his influence specifically in terms of belief in CH. I still don't see any evidence of belief in CH being widespread as you claim, due to Connes or otherwise.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I wrote specifically "The answer to your question ***may*** be geography-dependent." While this seems plausible in view of Connes' influence as you say, the subject requires further study.

Comment: Ah, fair, I misread that bit; sorry.